# I need to add a logo on my Webpart sub-site in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part

I need to add a logo on my web part sub site. Please see image below. How do I do this? The one on the right is just a place holder but the one on left is live and has link assigned to it.

[image]

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: Please clarify. Ideally, people post their code to obtain help on what they are trying to do.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I don't get what you mean with "Webpart subsite" - is that a web part, a subsite or a web part used to display a subsite? Web site logos can be changed from the site setting page, and if this is a web part it depends on the web part you use, with the web part begin OOTB or custom developed an huge discriminant.

Comment: ..so far I have tried to change the logo by going to the settings page and click on look and feel option, and that did not work as it replaced the logo for the page not exactly for the web part used to display a subsite. I also went to web part properties and navigated appearance, lay-out and advance options but I did not find a way to change the logo from there. I am not sure exactly where to go to perform add the logo. Your response it appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the picture that looks like a promoted links app. (Hovering over the image should bring up a dark over lay where text can be displayed).

To change/add images you need to change the view, easiest if you go via site contents and then change the view to All Promoted Links. This will change the view from a tabular layout to a grid layout.

Under the background image column add a link to the logo.